# Use of Global variable vs Parameter to a function

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need a piece of advice on the best practices for win forms.

I want to know what is better - using a global variable in a function or passing that variable as a parameter to the function.
So this global variable was assigned something in FormLoad() and then later on used in functions. This global variable may be modified in functions.

Please have a look at the code below:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<Employee> _employees;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Fill _employees Here
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Func1();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Func2(_employees);
    }

    private void Func1()
    {
        //Code uses _employees
    }

    private void Func2(List<Employee> employees)
    {
        //Code uses employees
    }    

    public class Employee
    {
       //Something 
    }
}
```

What do you think is better? `Func1()` or `Func2(parameter)`?.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: if the form deals with one employee, then having a private class member representing the data of that employee is reasonable. what do you mean when you write "global" though?

Comment: @D-Shih the application is kind of a test project, not coming from the database. Things are being dynamically created. The above was just an example. My whole point of using that was to maintain that object. e.g. If I have made removed some employee or sorted it I wanted that the next action(btn click) could access it.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having a class level variable which you have. In an event driven system like windows forms you need it to be class level as there's no way for you to pass that list from Form1_Load to anywhere else.

Comment: FYI some answers here, still opinions in my view  https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/146508/passing-member-variable-as-a-method-parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data that are temporary should be local.

```
class EmployeeHelper
{
    public Employee FindEmployee(string id)
    {
        List<Employee> temporaryList = GetEmployees();  //Use then throw away
        return temporaryList.Single( e => e.Id == id );
    }
}
```

Data that persist with the class should be member variables.

```
class Employees
{
    private List<Employee> _list;  //Keep around as long as the object exists
}
```

In general it is [better](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil) for a function to receive all of its dependencies as parameters rather than reading them from higher-scoped variables:

```
string BadFunction()
{
    return Globals.A + " " + Globals.B;  //Accessing global variables is confusing
}

string GoodFunction(string a, string b)
{
    return a + " " + b;  //Clear, and also idempotent
}
```

But this rule can be set aside if a class represents a collection of cohesive variables comprising the state of an logical idea:

```
class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set ; }        
    public string LastName { get; set ; }

    public string GetFullName()
    {
        return FirstName + " " + LastName;   //Would be silly to pass in the first and last names here
    }
}
```

Now in your case, you have a hybrid that is very common in WinForms... a class that represents a form which is a *view* into some object, in this case a list of employees. This makes it sort of ambiguous whether these data should be passed around or accessed as member variables. I can only provide these rules of thumb:

If the variable represents a list that is hard-bound to the code, access it globally. For example, if the purpose of the method is to update a control that is bound to that data item, and the data item *must* be in that list, then access the variable as a member variable:

```
class Form1 : Form
{
    List<Employee> _list;  

    public Form1()
    {
        _list = GetEmployees();
        this.MyList.DataSource = _list;
    }

    void ShowEmployeeName(string id)
    {
        var e = _list.Single( e => e.Id == id );
        this.NameLabel.Text = e.Name;
    }
}
```

If it is more general purpose, then pass the list in, since you might want to be able to pass in a different list some day:

```
class Form1 : Form
{
    List<Employee> _list;  

    string GetEmployeeName(List<Employee> list, string id)
    {
        var e = list.Single( e => e.Id == id );
        return e.Name;
    }
}
```

And of course the most object-oriented way to do it is to make the method a member of the class instead a member of the form:

```
class EmployeeList : List<Employee>
{
    public Func1() {  DoSomething(); }
}

class Form1 : Form
{
    protected EmployeeList _list;

    public void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _list.Func1();
    }
}
```

This last option is probably the best practice, since it separates the UI logic from the domain logic.

Comment: So you think that not passing the parameters in my example is not a bad idea. I am not judging anybody, but somebody else will be judging me on that :D   
I am using non parameter functions for now  e.g. Func1() and wanted to know if that was the best practice

Comment: Added a couple more examples. The last example is "best" IMO.

Comment: How will the new EmployeeList class use the variable initialized in formload()? Pass it as a constructor?

Comment: @Sameer It won't use it. It will replace it. It inherits from `List<Employee>` so it can already do everything the list did, and now you can extend it with `Func1`, etc. as much as you want.

Answer (score 2):

In general case I'd keep *both* versions as *overloaded methods*:

```
// if no data provided, use default - _employees
private void Func()
{
    Func(_employees);
}

// In case of explicit data provided - use it
//TODO: set employees type being as general as you can; 
// at least IList<Employee> or even IEnumerable<Employee> if it's possible
private void Func(IList<Employee> employees)
{
    ...
}
```